# How exactly should we combine these 3 snippet parts into one html file

Tags: jquery, html, css

I saw this snippet consisting of three parts:

http://jsfiddle.net/nBzcb/

there is html. There is jquery. And css.

I tried to combine that into a single file like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Hello World</title>
<style>
#content {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    left: 1%;
    right: 1%;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function resize()  {
        $(window).off('resize', resize);
        setTimeout(function () {
            var content = $('#content');
            var top = (window.innerHeight - content.height()) / 2;
            content.css('top', Math.max(0, top) + 'px');
            $(window).on('resize', resize);
        }, 50);
    }).resize();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content" style="background:#f00">
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

It doesn't seem to work. It seems that jquery, which is a library, need to be "referred". But how?

What should I do to fix that?

Comment: You need to include the jQuery library. See this link for more info: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: [No reason for JavaScript](https://jsfiddle.net/nwe82x00/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to include jQuery in the `head`, for example like this:

```
<script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
          integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
          crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try placing this in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a jquery library to run JQuery scripts.

Add CDNs similar to this before your scripts

```
 <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or simply

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" data-pagespeed-orig-type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can vary the versions

Also preferably put all the Javascript/Jquery at the bottom just before the ending 'body' tag. This will load it last and help in page load speed.

Actually it is always advisable to load Javascript and CSS as separate files (.js / .css ) loaded asynchronously. Except for above the fold CSS that should (as per Google page Insight) be included inline in style tags.

Comment: for everybody. That's what I expected. Boy. It's very hard to find that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include Jquery library to run jquery script on your webpage..
Just place this line of code in your HTML head tag..

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or if You are using localhost then first you have to download jquery library from [here](http://jquery.com/download/) and place that jquery file in HTML head tag as a external script.